# Performance loss when having too many files in /etc/cron.d?

Tags: cron, crontab

Is there an amount of files in `/etc/cron.d` that would lead to worse performance?

There are currently about 50 jobs in. In the future there can be up to 200 files in.

Am I correct to expect the cron daemon to  keep the files in-memory until they change?

Comment: This question is extremely dependent upon your exact scenario. I could put a single file in `/etc/cron.d` that makes the entire system crawl to a halt, and I could put 1000 files in there that wouldn't have the slightest effect upon the system. The number of files, by itself, holds no correlation to the performance (other than if you put so many files in a single folder that it's slow to traverse the directory, but that has nothing directly to do with cron)

Comment: @DarthAndroid thanks for your feedback. Technically cutting down the question, it would be: *What's the cost of `Jul  8  11:01:01 srv019 crond[1289]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/job_132)` ?*

Comment: I would argue that depends very much on the contents of `job_132`. Normally I wouldn't worry about having lots of cronjobs and one or two occasionally being added or updated unless they were *all* changing frequently. At that point, you're probably better off with some sort of custom software daemon that handles your tasks efficiently. That said, if the system isn't seeing issues with 50 jobs, I wouldn't worry about 200 of the same type/size of jobs.

Comment: @DarthAndroid I have implemented a watchdog that saves the memory peak and duration in database, everything is fine. Most jobs run within a few seconds or minutes, others run for a few hours. Files won't get changed often. Thanks for your feedback again, I think I'll keep everything this way. Anacron seems intelligent enough to handle all the files.